# How to load axioms inferred from protege and filter them by using OWL api

Tags: jena, owl-api

I'm using a plugin for protege named DLMiner to reason hypotheses. want I want is to select these hypotheses that contain some class or relationship.

for example, there are two hypotheses:

Client SubClassOf isOwnerof some Account

Loan SubClassof isLoanOf some owl:Thing

and I want hypotheses that contain Client, so the first one should be selected.
besides, there are some metrics (assumption, lift, precision,support) about each hypotheses, and I want these metrics can be also selected.

following is a sample contain two hypotheses:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://owl.cs.man.ac.uk/dlminer_6020e73c-5d3e-434a-9172-924d14f4e948#"
     xml:base="http://owl.cs.man.ac.uk/dlminer_6020e73c-5d3e-434a-9172-924d14f4e948"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:www="http://www.dlminer.io#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://owl.cs.man.ac.uk/dlminer_6020e73c-5d3e-434a-9172-924d14f4e948"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Annotation properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.dlminer.io#assumption -->

    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.dlminer.io#assumption"/>



    <!-- http://www.dlminer.io#lift -->

    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.dlminer.io#lift"/>



    <!-- http://www.dlminer.io#precision -->

    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.dlminer.io#precision"/>



    <!-- http://www.dlminer.io#support -->

    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.dlminer.io#support"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoan -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoan"/>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasStatementIssuanceFrequency -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasStatementIssuanceFrequency"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Account -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Account">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasStatementIssuanceFrequency"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Account"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasStatementIssuanceFrequency"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">3.7477272727272726</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">2200.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Running -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Running"/>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // General axioms
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoan"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Running"/>
                <rdfs:subClassOf>
                    <owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasStatementIssuanceFrequency"/>
                        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue"/>
                    </owl:Restriction>
                </rdfs:subClassOf>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedSource>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasStatementIssuanceFrequency"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">3.7477272727272726</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">201.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi -->
```

so, if the focus terms is "Account", I want the  print content is:

Account SubClassOf hasStatementIssuanceFrequency some StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue
Support: 2200, Assumption:0, Precision:1.

I have tried to use Jena to achieve my goal but I can just pick out the hypotheses I need by analysis the relationship between triple. however, I can't match the metrics with hypothesis, because I found that the reading order is random. I'm not sure if this is some sort of jena reading rule.

so, I wonder whether I can achieve my goal by using OWL api, I would appreciate it if you could provide me with a complete example. thx

another sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://owl.cs.man.ac.uk/dlminer_2ff7f586-ee56-400a-89a9-936c6d890678#"
     xml:base="http://owl.cs.man.ac.uk/dlminer_2ff7f586-ee56-400a-89a9-936c6d890678"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:www="http://www.dlminer.io#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://owl.cs.man.ac.uk/dlminer_2ff7f586-ee56-400a-89a9-936c6d890678"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Annotation properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.dlminer.io#assumption -->

    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.dlminer.io#assumption"/>



    <!-- http://www.dlminer.io#lift -->

    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.dlminer.io#lift"/>



    <!-- http://www.dlminer.io#precision -->

    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.dlminer.io#precision"/>



    <!-- http://www.dlminer.io#support -->

    <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.dlminer.io#support"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#IsLoanOf -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#IsLoanOf"/>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoanStatusValue -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoanStatusValue"/>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasStatementIssuanceFrequency -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasStatementIssuanceFrequency"/>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isCreditCardOf -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isCreditCardOf"/>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isOwnerOf -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isOwnerOf"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Account -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Account">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasStatementIssuanceFrequency"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Account"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasStatementIssuanceFrequency"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">3.7477272727272726</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">2200.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Classic -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Classic">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isCreditCardOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Classic"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isCreditCardOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">19.67780429594272</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">302.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Client -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Client">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isOwnerOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Client"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isOwnerOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">15.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">3.7223476297968396</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.9932279909706546</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">2200.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#CreditCard -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#CreditCard">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isCreditCardOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Client"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isCreditCardOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#CreditCard"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isCreditCardOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Client"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">19.67780429594272</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">419.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#CreditCard"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#isCreditCardOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">19.67780429594272</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">419.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Loan -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Loan">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#IsLoanOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Loan"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#IsLoanOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">28.139931740614337</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">293.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#LoanStatusValue -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#LoanStatusValue"/>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#OKRunningLoan -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#OKRunningLoan">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#IsLoanOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoanStatusValue"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#LoanStatusValue"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#OKRunningLoan"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#IsLoanOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">28.139931740614337</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">182.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#OKRunningLoan"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoanStatusValue"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#LoanStatusValue"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">28.139931740614337</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">182.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#OKStatus -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#OKStatus"/>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Running -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Running">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#OKRunningLoan"/>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#IsLoanOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoanStatusValue"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#OKStatus"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoanStatusValue"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Running"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#OKRunningLoan"/>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">19.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">41.01990049751244</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.9054726368159204</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">182.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Running"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#IsLoanOf"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">28.139931740614337</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">201.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Running"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoanStatusValue"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#OKStatus"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">19.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">28.494740040256733</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.9054726368159204</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">182.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>
    <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Running"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#hasLoanStatusValue"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:annotatedTarget>
        <www:assumption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.0</www:assumption>
        <www:lift rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">28.139931740614337</www:lift>
        <www:precision rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1.0</www:precision>
        <www:support rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">201.0</www:support>
    </owl:Axiom>



    <!-- http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue"/>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi -->
```

Comment: @ssz thx your answer.  I had removed some content of the former ontologies I provided, maybe it causes the RDF/XML incorrect, and I replaced it with a full version.

Comment: lol. Although I have achieved a part of  my goal - finding an axiom and printing by using jena, as a beginner, my code looks complicated and I think there must be another way. so I would appreciate it if you can provide me with method in your own way. thx again.

Answer (score 1):

Using OWL-API(v5.1.11) and `ManchesterOWLSyntaxOWLObjectRendererImpl` from owlapi-parsers, the following way is working for me:

```
        OWLOntologyManager m = OntManagers.createOWL();
        OWLOntology o = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(data);
        OWLClass c = m.getOWLDataFactory().getOWLClass("http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#Account");
        OWLAxiom a = o.axioms(c)
                .filter(x -> AxiomType.SUBCLASS_OF.equals(x.getAxiomType()))
                .sorted() // to have the same order every time
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(AssertionError::new);
        OWLObjectRenderer r = new ManchesterOWLSyntaxOWLObjectRendererImpl();
        String res = r.render(a) + " " + a.annotations()
                .map(x -> x.getProperty().getIRI().getShortForm() + ": " +
                        x.getValue().asLiteral().orElseThrow(AssertionError::new).parseDouble())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        System.out.println(res);
```

The output:

```
Account SubClassOf hasStatementIssuanceFrequency some StatementIssuanceFrequencyValue assumption: 0.0, lift: 3.7477272727272726, precision: 1.0, support: 2200.0
```

Note that `ManchesterOWLSyntaxOWLObjectRendererImpl` is not part of public interfaces, and therefore may be changed, so it is better to write your own `OWLObjectRenderer` or another way to make `String` representation of desired axiom.

Comment: Great! it also works for me. now I have another question: as there are not only one hypothesis that contain the focus terms, so the output may not be a single one. therefore, how to sort these hypothesis?  I just put the hypothesis into a string and simply rank them according to their length.  so, does there exist ways to sort these hypothesis? like logic strength or other? I put another sample with more hypotheses in the question description， and the focus term can be set as "Running"

Comment: This question is about Java, not Jena or OWL-API or OWL. Use Stream-API. `OWLObject` is `Comparable`, so you can just sort the stream using the natural order. Or provide your own `Comparator`. RDF itself does not guarantee order, so you are right assuming that if there are several `<c> rdfs:subClassOf _:bx` statements, it is not defined what will be picked up. Since you are keeping info as annotation assertions, in case of custom comparator you need to sort annotations. And filter by them. Note: annotations are not a common way to keep info - usually data property assertions are used for it.

Comment: In the code shown in the response, the list of axioms is already sorted (by OWLObject compareTo()) and the first element selected. If you need to carry out the same operation on all the results, just use all elements in the stream instead of stopping at `findFirst()`.